# How would I go about fixing this Mako syntax highlighter?

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

This error pops up every time I try to use this syntax highlighter in Sublime Text. I'm not sure how I would go about fixing it and Google doesn't seem to show any results. Would anyone here happen to be an XML / TM Syntax guru who could help?

The Error.
    Error loading syntax file Packages/HTML Mako/HTML (Mako).tmLanguage: Unknown include 
    #embedded-code

I'm just going to link to the file as it's a rather large XML document and I don't think it'd be very nice of me to paste it in its entirety here.
http://pastebin.com/ZjU51RCG

Oh and the references to the embedded-code are at lines 892, 928, 995 and 1032.

Comment: Try the bundle at https://bitbucket.org/hassing/mako-tmbundle. It seems to have been updated recently

Answer (score 4):

This is not really fix to that XML, but I just wrote yesterday an addition to Python bundle to support Mako templates.

Just copy this http://pastebin.com/tLgU6P68 to Packages/Python/Mako.tmLanguage and you should get simple highlighting support that recognizes most of mako tags and Python blocks.

If any problems please leave a comment. I'm using build 2165 on osx.

Comment: Do you want to have a look at this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211640? It will be nice to know if that will work.